# Not receiving any firebase push notifications when android smart watch goes to deep sleep or doze mode in Android N

Tags: android, performance, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FirebaseMessagingService for push to my android smart watch. But after leaving the watch untouched for sometime like 1 or 2 hours, it stopped receiving any push until I wake it. My app is a Device Admin app. Also I've provided "Ignore Battery Optimizations" and whitelist the app.And I've tried sending high priority push as well but nothing works for me. Here is my code:

```
{
   "to":"IOYbvsd799fhsagdashdabgyd_cLbSVD4DlZgfjMKwKvZhJHiKR4DIzpMrX8zUL15C_adfyEcrlI9q6zOFqFs_zwNPTVIDm-v20ZK0qgagKYGaQE1OPBqdH4P_JHYIXOIS3gfn",
    "priority": "high",
    "data":{
    "field1":"field1",
    "field2":"field2"
    }
}
```

In manifest file:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />

<service
        android:name=".service.FirebaseService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

By default FirebaseService is "never" dies, but watch has battery optimization that can't controlled by developer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.... I've whitelisted the google play services from battery optimization so it will never die and also programmatically adjust wifi settings to run even in deep sleep. Now watch is receiving notifications even its in sleep mode.

Thanks..

Comment: How did you programmatically adjust the wifi settings to run even in deep sleep?